# Outbound rules don't apply inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, updatepanel, url-rewrite-module

TLDR: Outbound rules are not applying within updatepanel partial postbacks

---

I'm Using the IIS 7.5 URL Rewriter to map image paths to a cdn.

Here's a simplified version of what's happening

```
<Repeater Goes Here>

    <img alt="alt text" src="<%#getImageSource(Eval("Filename").ToString() )%>">

<End of Repeater>
```

let's say the function getImageSource returns `"/images/someimage.jpg"`

this in turn rewrites to

```
<img alt="alt text" src="http://img.cdn.com/someimage.jpg">
```

the outbound rule that makes this work is:

```
    <rule name="Out_Rewrite_ServeCookieLessImages" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml" enabled="true">
      <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="^/Images/(.*)$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="http://img.cdn.com/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>

    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd.*$" negate="true"/>
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
```

The problem is that when using the repeater inside an Update Panel

the actual html that's outputted after an async postback is

```
<img alt="alt text" src="/Images/someimage.jpg">
```

instead of

```
<img alt="alt text" src="http://img.cdn.com/someimage.jpg">
```

How would i make the updatepanel parse the output correctly?

Thanks in advance

---

Edit: My guess at this point is that it has to do something with the page lifecycle... or perhaps the order in which the rewrite module is called...will keep updated

Answer (score 3):

The response content type returned by the server when using an UpdatePanel is text/plain instead of text/html.

The ResponseIsHtml precondition you have listed will only match text/html content, so that is why the UpdatePanel response is not being rewritten.

If you modify the input regex to catch text/plain, then your content will be rewritten as it should:

```
<preConditions>
  <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml">
    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/[html|plain]"/>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd.*$" negate="true"/>
  </preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

Unfortunately, there is an issue with doing this for which I have not yet found the solution - having the response rewritten causes the UpdatePanel ajax manager to throw a ys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException.